# Campo data 01/01/0001

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Estou com um projeto [asp.net-mvc3](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc3) que possui uma *View* que tem um campo para receber um tipo `DateTime`. No banco de dados esse campo é obrigatório.

O problema é que sempre quando eu acesso à respectiva *View*, esse campo vem preenchido com 01/01/0001, o que me obriga a ter que apagá-lo sempre.

Como posso fazer para que esse campo venha em branco?

Propriedade da classe:

```c-sharp
[DataType(DataType.Date)] 
public System.DateTime DataDaSolicitacaoDeSaida { get; set; }
```

Propriedade da View:

```razor
<p class="linha">
    <label class="w100" for="DataDaSolicitacaoDeSaida"> Data da solicitação de saída </label> 
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataDaSolicitacaoDeSaida) 
</p>
```

Comment: Cole a View, ActionResult, e a Classe que gera tal View por favor ?

Comment: Propriedade da classe:

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public System.DateTime DataDaSolicitacaoDeSaida { get; set; }

Propriedade da View
            <p class="linha">
            <label class="w100" for="DataDaSolicitacaoDeSaida">
                Data da solicitação de saída:</label>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataDaSolicitacaoDeSaida)

            </p>

Comment: Em todos os navegadores dá nisso?

Comment: @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DataDaSolicitacaoDeSaida), muda para TextBoxFor ???

Comment: Sim, isso é inserido pelo próprio código

Answer (score 6):

Você deve definir a propriedade como nullable, e colocar o data-annotation
`Required` sobre o campo.

Como já há outra resposta dizendo isso, vou explicar da forma mais detalhada que eu conseguir.

### Nullable? Isso não faz sentido...

Isso faz sentido sim... uma view-model
é um modelo que serve para intercambio de dados entre o controller e a view.
Se a view pode aparecer com o valor da propriedade vazio ao invocar a operação
CRUD de criação, então faz sentido que esta propriedade seja nullable,
pois este é o estado inicial, apesar de ser inválido...
fato este que é tratado pelo annotation `Required` sem problemas.

Se você não fizer a propriedade ser nullable, então não poderá passar um
view-model para a view de criação (ou seja, é o mesmo que passar `null` para a view)...
a meu ver parece aceitável, mas eu gosto de ter controle,
então eu sempre chamo a view de criação assim:

```
return this.View(new MeuViewModel());
```

Assim quando eu precisar passar algum valor default, para a view de criação,
eu posso fazer isso:

```
// eu quero que a opção 'OpcaoDoUsuario' já venha checked, na view de criação
return this.View(new MeuViewModel { OpcaoDoUsuario = true });
```

Ou então eu poderia alterar o construtor de `MeuViewModel`, já inicializando o valor padrão.

### Annotation Required

`Required` serve para dizer: **se o valor associado à propriedade for nulo ou
vazio, então o modelo é inválido**. Não importa se o valor da propriedade é
anulável ou não. Acontece que a validação pode ser feita no client, ou no
server. O MVC 5 pode usar o atributo `required` para fazer validação client-side
o que não é uma regra. O MVC 3 também possui validação client. Em todos os
casos anteriores, seja a propriedade nullable ou não, nenhuma entra em conflito
conceitual com o atributo `Required`.

### Use Html.EditorFor

Na view use `EditorFor`. Existem vários motivos para isso:

- este método irá gerar campos HTML com os prefixos de template corretamente,
  o que é necessário quando trabalhando com mestre-detalhe e com EditorTemplates.
- este método vai obedecer aos formatos indicados via annotation:
  `DisplayFormat`, `DataType`, entre outros.
- este método irá renderizar os controles mais aproprieados para lidar com o
  tipo de dados. Se você não gostar da forma que foi renderizado, pode facilmente
  criar um EditorTemplate para contornar o problema, usando o annotation
  `UIHint("NomeDoEditorPersonalizado")`.

### Não use Html.TextBoxFor

Posso confirmar que, tanto no ASP.NET MVC 3, como no 4, como no 5,
`TextBoxFor` lê e renderiza o valor da propriedade que for passada para ele,
a não ser que o view-model passado seja nulo.

Se a propriedade for um `DateTime`, que é um value-type cujo valor
padrão é `01/01/0001 00:00:00` então é isso que será renderizado. Se for um
`int`, o valor padrão é `0`, e nesse caso é isso que será renderizado.

Só não vai ser renderizado o valor padrão do tipo, caso um valor seja definido
manualmente.

Além disso, esse método ignora todas as tentativas de formatá-lo usando
annotations: `DisplayFormat`, `DataType`, `UIHint`...

**Quando usar TextBoxFor**

Eu não vejo nenhum motivo para usar este método. Nunca!

Se você for usar um plugin de date-picker, que requer uma `<input type="text" />`,
então use um EditorTemplate, que além de tudo, encapsule o uso do plugin.

### Não use Html.TextBox

Não use o método `TextBox` para criar um campo do modelo.
Este método não leva em conta o uso de prefixo de template,
que é necessário em visualizações do tipo mestre-detalhe,
e no uso de templates de edição `EditorTemplates` quando aplicável
([`ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.templateinfo.htmlfieldprefix(v=vs.118).aspx)).

### Referência

- [What is use of UIHint attribute in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196372/what-is-use-of-uihint-attribute-in-mvc)
- [TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.templateinfo.htmlfieldprefix%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)
- [How to remove time part from DateTime variable in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550569/how-to-remove-time-part-from-datetime-variable-in-mvc)
- [Exploring Display and Editor Templates in ASP.NET MVC3/4](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/672591/Exploring-Display-and-Editor-Templates-in-ASP-NET)
- [ASP.NET MVC 4 Editor Template for basic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655930/asp-net-mvc-4-editor-template-for-basic-types)

Comment: Um grande número de programadores ainda busca evitar o ViewModel e faz tudo nas próprias classes de domínio quando usam code-first.

Comment: Programação é igual a seleção natural, agente nunca sabe o que é melhor ou pior até tentar e mensurar... eu mesmo já usei classes de domínio na view, e não tive grandes problemas, entretanto, sempre acabava precisando de algo mais nas views, e tinha que ir criando view-models à medida do necessário.

Comment: Usar classes de domínio como sendo de visão, vai se transformar em trabalho de manutenção, ao invés de trabalho de criação... só tem um detalhe, manutenção é mais chato (me dá menos satisfação) do que criação, além de ser mais demorado, por causa do tempo necessário para localizar a classe a ser alterada, e depois pelo trabalho de verificar se a alteração causou efeitos colaterais ou não... **em suma:** eu aprendi que criar classes de visão separadas das de domínio é bom.

Answer (score 5):

O que acontece é que mesmo sendo nulo, o campo date vai possuir um valor, no caso, 01/01/0001.

Para resolver declare a propriedade como abaixo.

```cs
[Required]
public DateTime? MeuDateTime{ get; set; }
```

Comment: É... pelo que pesquisei também é isso mesmo. Confirma pra gente @user4849

Comment: Caros, conforme falei deixando a propriedade como Nullable o capo gerado não mostra mais a data 01/01/0001. Quando o post é acionado eu trato a data na controladora verificando sempre se a data é diferente de 01/01/0001

Comment: Você pode deixar a propriedade nullable, juntamente com o atributo required e na action verificar `ModelState.IsValid`, ao invés de verificar o valor `01/01/0001`... mesmo porque com a propriedade nullable, esse valor não voltará a aparece sozinho, a não ser que seja digitado pelo usuário.

Comment: Utilizando ASP.NET MVC 5 no VS.2013 eu tive o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 1):

Caros amigos, eu acredito que toda Tempestade de Idéias tem o seu valor, mas, no momento que vem e tem um posicionamento do tipo radical, eu me vi no direito de expor a solução real para essa dúvida ...

**A Classe**

```
public class Pessoa
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Nome { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DataAniversario { get; set; }
}
```

*Seguindo o mesmo tipo de campo e o mesmo DataType*

**Controller Sem Gerar Data 01/01/0001**

```
public class PessoasController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Pessoas/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Criar()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

**Controller com Data 01/01/0001**

```
public class PessoasController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Pessoas/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Criar()
        {
            return View(new Pessoa());
        }
    }
```

A diferença desses dois Controller no Metodo ActionResult Criar é que um não manda Model e o outro manda uma Instância do Model (***new Pessoa()***) e nesse momento é que a Data fica *01/01/0001*.

**Imagem do Controller sem Gerar Data 01/01/0001**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Imagem do Controller com a Data 01/01/0001**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Página Gerada sem 01/01/0001**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Página Gerada com 01/01/0001**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu pedi várias vezes que ele colocasse o código daquela **ActionResult**, mas, infelizmente nunca colocou.
Concluindo, eu fiz a mesma coisa utilizando conceitos proposta pela ferramenta, sem a inserção de código desnecessários e, mais não procurando artifícios para ratificar o meu conhecimento. A Solução talvez proposta só condiz com a realidade do nosso amigo, mas, eu por exemplo, nos meus Sistemas MVC ASP.NET nunca precisei fazer tal código, porque, eu estudo o modelo conceitual antes implementar ...
Peço mil desculpas, mas, eu tenho que propor num grupo tão famoso que seja elaborados testes antes de mais nada ...

Obrigado!